# Не могу вставить картинку в css

Tags: html, css

Делал все по одному видео.

Сделал все в точь, в точь

но уже в начале появились проблемы с картинкой

вот видео -----> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6l3ZSOQKE5g&t=5125s

```css
header {
  background: url(../img/first-bg.jpg) no-repeat center top / cover;
  height: 600px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>golden</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/Style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <div class="container">

    </div>
  </header>

  <section>
    <div class="container">

    </div>
  </section>

  <section>
    <div class="container">

    </div>
  </section>

  <section>
    <div class="container">

    </div>
  </section>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Возможно путь к файл не правильно. Некоторые браузер не поддерживает cover.

Comment: Покажите иерархию Ваших файлов в проекте.

Comment: а картинка есть в папке? или путь к картинке может проверить? судя по коду ваш стилевой файл лежит в папке , вы из него выходите и заходите в папку img а там картинка.

Answer (score 0):

```css
header {
  background: url(https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/07/28/22/03/fireworks-865104_960_720.jpg) no-repeat center top;
  background-size:  cover;
 height:var(--height);
}

:root {
--height: 100px
}

section:nth-child(odd) {
background: yellow;
height:var(--height);
}

section:nth-child(even) {
background: green;
height:var(--height);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>golden</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/Style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <div class="container">

</div>
  </header>

  <section>
    <div class="container">

    </div>
  </section>

  <section>
    <div class="container">

    </div>
  </section>

  <section>
    <div class="container">

    </div>
  </section>

</body>

</html>
```